# how to import from libs in NX

Tags: nestjs, microservices, nomachine-nx

I have Microservice with **Nestjs** and **Nx**

this is project structure

```
project
│   
│
└───apps
│   │ gateway
│   │ auth
│   
│   
└───libs
    └───common
```

now I want to import some module from `libs/common` in gateway

```
import { RMQ_SERVICES } from '@app/common/constants/rmq.constant';
```

but it doesn't work

**Cannot find module '@app/common/constants/rmq.constant' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)**

I have also tried this

```
import { RMQ_SERVICES } from 'libs/common/src/lib/constants/rmq.constant';
```

but it doesn't worked .

**Projects cannot be imported by a relative or absolute path, and must begin with a npm scopeeslint**

so how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these were created with the nx generators then your `tsconfig.base.json` should contain the proper `paths` for mapping the libraries. Generally your `nx.json` will have an `npmScope` property that is your `@scope/` and then depending on how you set up the `--importPath` option that should define what path you need to use. Check your base `tsconfig.base.json` to see what the path is otherwise. I usually have libraries like `@scope/server/kysely` or `@scope/shared/types` in my Nx monorepos, [like this one here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/unteris).

If these were **not** created with the Nx generators, then you'll need to add the path mapping to your `tsconfig.base.json` yourself and make sure that the `tsconfig.json` of your applications are updated to extend from the base config